# QT, updateGL() slows down ui interaction

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I developed a program which reads bitmap raw data from socket and it signals it to glWidget object. that object would render the bitmap to the screen. The problem I have is the program slows down the ui interaction. Here is the QUdpSocket class initiated inside MainWindow:

```
    while(sum > 0)
        {
            QByteArray datagram;

            if(udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize() == -1){
                usleep(1000);
                continue;
}
                datagram.resize(udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize());
            //qDebug() << "udp:" << udpsocket->pendingDatagramSize();
            udpsocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), host, &myPort);

            sumPacket.append(datagram);

            sum -= datagram.size();

            qDebug() << loop;
            loop++;
        }

        if(sum == 0){
        emit dataReceivedClientImage(sumPacket);
        }
```

When I receive a packet it is signaled to GlWidget class to render it to the screen like this:

```
void GlWidget::createTextureFromBitmap(QByteArray btmp)
{
    bytes.clear();
    bytes.resize(size * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));

    bytes = btmp;
    updateGL();
    qDebug() << "updated..";
```

and finally glPaint() would do:

```
void GlWidget::paintGL()
{
    //! [5]
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glDrawPixels(window_width,window_height,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,bytes.constData());
```

As I tested the program, reading from socket does not slow down ui interaction. What it does is the processing of the data following updateGl() functionto render to the screen. is there any way that I can make my ui interaction faster?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "ui interaction"?

Comment: There are some button in the ui in which when clicked would deal with serial device. The glWidget however, in on the other side, showing images or rendering via glDrawPixels.

Comment: A suggestion would be to insure all non-UI data processing happens on a separate thread. You don't want to interfere with button clicks because youre calculating the new image buffer. You can always calculate and throw the result back to the UI thread.

Comment: I know, but I need to render to the screen, is it possible to define the glwidget object inside a thread and connect the signal from the socket (when the data is read) to the thread, so it can handle the processing? this way the run() method of thread remain empty (no using of that part).

Comment: I know, but I need to render to the screen, is it possible to define the glwidget object inside a thread and connect the signal from the socket (when the data is read) to the thread, so it can handle the processing? this way the run() method of thread remain empty (no using of that part).

Comment: You should only put your non-UI operations in a thread. Qt won't allow you to create anything that is UI related on a separate thread from the UI thread.